# Viewmodel convert into Json fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to convert the viewmodel into httpcontent to pass the viewmodal. I want to call post method of web api from another web api using url, my code is mentioned below, The post method is hitting correctly but the viewmodal is null, please anybody help me to pass the viewmodal into postasync method.

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:89**2/");
string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myViewModel);
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var result = client.PostAsync("api/abcd", byteContent).Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using StringContent for your post data.

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:89**2/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myViewModel), 
                                Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync("api/abcd", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this.

`client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:89**2/");
  string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myViewModel);
  var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var result = client.PostAsync("api/abcd", stringContent ).Result;`

We are considering that the problem is in the "client.PostAsync", but maybe it is in the api that is receiving the requisition, if the code below doesn't solve the problem, would you put here the code of the method that is receiving the requisition?